# File not created in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have installed ansible on one machine and trying to execute commands on another (remote) machinge.

1. Ansible successfully installed
2. Able to reach all hosts (local and remote). Tested with 
   **ansible all  -m ping**
   This was successful
3. Trying to execute a simple command again
   **ansible all -a 'echo "hello world" > ~/test'**
   Executed successfuly. But the file test is not created.

Cannot find the reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing a command via `ansible -a` is equivalent to the command module, see
[command module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html).
It is not processed via shell, therefore, `>>` (as well as other redirection operators) and `$HOME` are not available

In your case I would use

```
ansible -m 'shell' --args 'echo "hello world">>/home/ansibleremoteuser/test' all
```

In this case you would use the shell module which allows redirections.